# Does Windows Installer Count Partitions as Single Drives?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, windows-installation

I'm reinstalling Windows 10 on my Ubuntu Machine, but I have a question. So that I don't wipe Ubuntu when formatting the drive as NTFS so Windows can install on it, I have created a new 24GB Partition and formatted it in NTFS. So sorta like this:
[Screenshot of disks app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX29r.png)

My plan is to fire up Windows, delete the ext4 partition Ubuntu is on and expand my Windows partition in to the new unallocated space.
My question is: Will the Windows Installer treat this new NTFS partition as a drive available for Windows installation? I'm pretty sure it will, but I want to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to install Windows on whatever NTFS partition you tell it to install on per the setup options and that will assign the "C" drive letter by default for that partition that contains the core Windows OS. I don't think the drive letter is really relevant as that's just Windows assigning the letters to the partitions accordingly whether by default or overriding per the configurations. You will need to ensure that the partition size, format, etc. meets any prerequisites though so be sure to double check on those aspects.

Comment: That comment is in reference to: ***Will the Windows Installer treat this new NTFS partition as a drive available for Windows installation?***

Comment: In your first paragraph you say you don't want to wipe Ubuntu but in your second you say you want to delete it.  If you want to end up with just Windows you can delete ALL partitions from the Windows installer and it will create and format what it requires.  If you want to install Windows and keep Ubuntu, yes, it will install to the NTFS partition if you format it as such (or it will install to an unallocated space if you don't format it).

Comment: What I'm saying is I don't want to format the primary partition as NTFS, so if Windows fails I have something to fall back on.